# What's the workaround for storing/retrieving enums in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, enums

To start with, I think it's my fault that I only started using Firebase that late in the project.

Anyway, what I want to do, is to store a Pub object into a database. It contains various information, such as opening hours, ratings, facilities etc.

The problem is not in the storing, is that whenever I try to get a list of pubs from the database, I get this problem

This is the error.

```
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Could not find enum value of com.example.matasolutions.pintindex.Day for value "Monday"
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToEnum(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:302)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:212)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:178)
```

This is the enum class.

```
public enum Day {
    MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY
};
```

This is what a constructor with enum looks like

```
public SingleOpeningHours(Day dayOfTheWeek,String openingTime, String closingTime){

        this.dayOfTheWeek = dayOfTheWeek;
        this.openingTime = openingTime;
        this.closingTime = closingTime;

    }
```

and finally, this is how it gets added to the list and then to the database.

```
  ArrayList<SingleOpeningHours> singleOpeningHours = new ArrayList<SingleOpeningHours>();

        singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.MONDAY, "09:00", "00:00"));
        singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.TUESDAY, "09:00", "01:00"));
        singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.WEDNESDAY, "09:00", "01:00"));
        singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.THURSDAY, "09:00","01:00"));
        singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.FRIDAY, "09:00", "01:00"));
        singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.SATURDAY, "09:00", "01:00"));
        singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.SUNDAY, "09:00", "01:00"));
```

EDIT: I've got 7 enum classes that are associated with objects being stored. What's the best workaround for this? Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Database doesn't support enum data types. To see more about supported data types check [Supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)

Solution 1:(Easiest)
Just use Strings for the Days without making an enum

Change dayOfTheWeek as String

```
String dayOfTheWeek; // Changed from Day to String

public SingleOpeningHours(String dayOfTheWeek,String openingTime, String closingTime){

    this.dayOfTheWeek = dayOfTheWeek;
    this.openingTime = openingTime;
    this.closingTime = closingTime;

}
```

And use a string in singleOpeningHours List as follows,

```
ArrayList<SingleOpeningHours> singleOpeningHours = new ArrayList<SingleOpeningHours>();

    singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours("MONDAY", "09:00", "00:00"));
    singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours("TUESDAY", "09:00", "01:00"));
```

Solution 2: Change the dayOfTheWeek used in SingleOpeningHours object to a string and use name() method in Enum Class to convert an enum value to a string

```
String dayOfTheWeek; // Changed from Day to String
String openingTime;
String closingTime;

public SingleOpeningHours(Day dayOfTheWeek,String openingTime, String closingTime){

this.dayOfTheWeek = dayOfTheWeek.name(); // make sure add .name()
this.openingTime = openingTime;
this.closingTime = closingTime;
```

}

And use enum Day in singleOpeningHours List(No change here)

```
ArrayList<SingleOpeningHours> singleOpeningHours = new ArrayList<SingleOpeningHours>();

singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.MONDAY, "09:00", "00:00"));
singleOpeningHours.add(new SingleOpeningHours(Day.TUESDAY, "09:00", "01:00"));
```

Hope these solutions will help you to solve your problem

Comment: enum Employee { Yes, No }

String _employee;

_employee = Employee.Yes doesn't work on me.